# how to speed up tail and head in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a giant text file called `stock_messages` that looks like this:

```
H: TSLA
A: id1, 100 
E: id1, 20
F: id2, 250
...
H: AAPL
A: id1, 100
A: id2, 20
E: id1, 80
A: id2, 10
...
```

What I want to do is to create a separate text file with messages for each stock (e.g. `AAPL.txt`, `TSLA.txt`, etc).

I wrote a bash script so that

```
start=-1
stock_name=""
grep -n -i '^H' $file | awk -F "[:,]" {'print $1, $NF'} | while read -r line; do
  line_number=$(echo $line | awk -F " " {'print $1'})
  if [[ "$start" -gt 0 ]]
  then
    tail -n "+start" $file | head -n "$(($line_number-$start))" > "./data/${stock_name}.txt"
    echo "saved $stock_name data!"
  fi
  start=$line_number
  stock_name=$(echo $line | awk -F " " {'print $2'})
done
```

Basically I'm taking the line numbers where `H`'s are, and using `tail` and `head` to take those lines out and save it into separate file.

The script runs pretty fast initially but it gets really slow very quickly, and I'm not sure why.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can rewrite this as a single `awk` script. No `head`, no `tail`, no using `awk` to output a single value.

Comment: isn't `awk` slower than `head` and `tail`?

Comment: Not if you run `awk` *once* vs running `head`, `tail`, and `awk` repeatedly.

Comment: aha i see. so i can actually do this with awk once.

Comment: You could also do `csplit  file  '/^H:/'` if you don't care about the file names being the same as the symbols.

Comment: can a stock show up more than once in your file?

Comment: @markp-fuso it only shows up once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `awk` is an option

```
$ awk '/^H:/ {close(stock_message); stock_message=$2".txt"} {print > stock_message}' input_file

$ cat AAPL.txt
H: AAPL
A: id1, 100
A: id2, 20
E: id1, 80
A: id2, 10
...

$ cat TSLA.txt
H: TSLA
A: id1, 100
E: id1, 20
F: id2, 250
...
```

Comment: Why use `:` as a FS at all? You can just have the trigger be `/^H:/`

Comment: @MoneyBall Depends on usage. In this case, this will be quicker as it processes it in a single pass, whereas your script calls numerous tools numerous times including `awk` to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I apologize but I'm not an expert in bash; could you explain to me what `close` is doing and why I don't need to use `-F`  in `awk`?

Comment: @MoneyBall Well, you can use `FS` if you want, but as  pointed out, it is redundant in this case as changing the default seperator is not needed if I had included `:` in the initial match. `close` closes the variable on each loop pass.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have another file with the following header format: `H|1|AAPL|383|...`. Similar to the file above, it contains messages of AAPL after the header, then a new header for a different stock and a list of messages, etc. I tried running `awk -F"|" '/^H/ {close(stock_message); stock_message=$3".txt"} {print > stock_message}' input_file` but I get `awk: cannot open "" for output(no such file or directory)`. I printed out `$3` which is the name of the stock. I'm not sure why this isn't working.